# How to setup deploy user with Chef-solo on Vagrantbox?

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

In my Vagrantfile I have:

```
  config.vm.network :hostonly, "192.168.1.20"
```

Now, how can I setup my user such that

```
ssh  deploy@192.168.1.20
```

works out of the box? (= after `vagrant up` and with Chef-solo provisioning?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ssh to your vagrantbox via the IP of the machine that hosts your vagrantbox. But you use a different port number, than the standard ssh port 22. Usually vagrant sets a port forward for the ssh port 22 of your vagrant box, to port 2222 of the hostmachine

```
ssh -p 2222 deploy@localhost
```

or

```
ssh -p 2222 deploy@<port of your host machine>
```

Of course you need to have chef create the deploy user within one of your cookbooks as described here: http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Resources#Resources-User

```
user "deploy" do
 comment "Deploy User"
 uid 1000
 gid "users"
 home "/home/deploy"
 shell "/bin/sh"
 password "$1$JJsvHslV$szsCjVEroftprNn4JHtDi."
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, if my question was not accurate enough, but this part: "create the deploy user within one of your cookbooks" is my problem; I am looking for a simple way to create the deploy user, that can then be used e.g. with ssh